# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, dbnull

i am receiving this problem

> Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.
>
> Line 501:                        hfSupEmail.Value =
>   dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail")

i am very new to this, i am not really sure what is the exact problem
could someone guide me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The quick and dirty fix:

```
hfSupEmail.Value = dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail").ToString()
```

or for C#:

```
hfsupEmail.Value = dt.Rows[0]["SupEmail"].ToString();
```

This works very well when your eventual target and the source data are already strings, because any extra `.ToString()` call for something that's already a string is likely to be optimized into a no-op by the jitter, and if it's NULL the resulting `DBNull.Value.ToString()` expression produces the empty string you want.

However, if you're working with non-string types, you may end up doing **significant** extra work, especially with something like a `DateTime` or numeric value where you want specific formatting. Remember, internationalization concerns mean parsing and composing date and number values are actually surprisingly expensive operations; doing "extra" work to avoid those operations is often more than worth it.

Comment: thanks for the help and explanation! now the application is working fine

Answer (score 7):

Hope This Help....
 `dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail")` returns null 
To avoid this chcek before assigning

```
If Not IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail")) Then
    hfSupEmail.Value = dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail")
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

You should handle it at DB query level itself.

```
instead of "select name from student", use "select IsNull(name,'') as name from student"
```

In this way, DB will handle your NULL value.

Comment: It's often much more efficient to do this work in the application tier.

Comment: Any specific reason? In my view, it is better to handle at DB level rather handling it at application level because at application you are engaging application server again to process the request.

Comment: Not "again": you do this as part of the same engagement. The  application server (or app itself directly) engages the DB, and handles this as part of that process.

DB servers are often expensive to license compared to app servers, and even when using free database engines they are often difficult to performance tune or scale out relative to application servers, such that cpu time and RAM on the app server are very cheap compared to processing time on the DB server.

Comment: Joel @ Please also have a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/36428/how-will-you-handle-null-values-in-your-application

One can debate on this. It depends use case to use case. So you are right too.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your `dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail")` is coming as NULL from DB and you cannot assign NULL to string property. Try replacing that line with:

```
hfSupEmail.Value = If(IsDbNull(dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail")), String.Empty, dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail").ToString)
```

The code checks if value is NULL and if it is - replaces it with empty string, otherwise uses original value.

Answer (score 1):

To handle it from code, here is a small extension method

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module HTMLExtensionMethods
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function DefaultIfDBNull(Of T)(ByVal obj As Object) As T
        Return If(Convert.IsDBNull(obj), CType(Nothing, T), CType(obj, T))
    End Function
End Module
```

Call it like this.

```
hfSupEmail.Value = dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail").DefaultIfDBNull(Of String)()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Field method of the Datarow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) combined with an [If Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) to check for a Null value in one line like this. If it is null, you can replace it with an empty string (or another string of your choosing):

```
hfSupEmail.Value = If(dt.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("SupEmail"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to just concatenate it with an empty string:

```
hfSupEmail.Value = dt.Rows(0)("SupEmail") & ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = " select  sum (Income_Amount)  from Income where Income_Month= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' and Income_year=" & txtyearpro.Text & ""
        cmd.Connection = con
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read = True Then
            txtincome1.Text = dr(0).ToString  ' ToString  converts null values into string '

        End If
```

Comment: Hello naasir please edit your question to abide by these rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask