# How to handle System.DBNull for string field?

Tags: c#, .net

For testing I introduced in my DB a row with a null field.
now I am receiving this error when I want get the record for updating:

[InvalidCastException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z61C1.png)

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

the code I am using works fine where all fields are not null, it is: for the model :

```
using System.Data;
namespace ContosoSite.Models.Services
{
    public class StudentEnrollmentList
    {
       public int ID { get; set; }
        public string? Grade { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public static StudentEnrollmentList FromDataRow (DataRow row)
        {
            StudentEnrollmentList studentEnrollmentList = new()
            {
                ID=(int)row["EnrollmentID"],
                Grade=(string)row["Grade"]+"",
                Title=(string)row["Title"],
                Credits=(int)row["Credits"]
            };
            return studentEnrollmentList;
        }
    }
}
```

and  for the controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            //in questo punto
            var student = await _context.GetStudent((int) id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(student);
        }
```

in the service I am using this:

```
    var studentCoursesDT=dataSet.Tables[1];
    foreach(DataRow row in studentCoursesDT.Rows)
    {
        StudentEnrollmentList enrollments = StudentEnrollmentList.FromDataRow(row);
        curStudent.Enrollments.Add(enrollments);
    }
```

so, if I can't get the entire record with all of the list  I can't update the error

Comment: This isn't a null reference issue.

Comment: Have you seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283360/conversion-from-type-dbnull-to-type-string-is-not-valid)?

Answer (score 0):

few minute ago I found this:

```
using System.Data;
```

namespace ContosoSite.Models.Services
{
public class StudentEnrollmentList
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string? Grade { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public int Credits { get; set; }

```
    public static StudentEnrollmentList FromDataRow (DataRow row)
    {
        StudentEnrollmentList studentEnrollmentList = new()
        {
            ID=(int)row["EnrollmentID"],
           // Grade=Value==DBNull?null:(string)row["Grade"],
           Grade=row.Field<string>("Grade"),
            Title=(string)row["Title"],
            Credits=(int)row["Credits"]
        };
        return studentEnrollmentList;
    }
}
```

}

and it was ok !

Answer (score 0):

If you want Grade as empty string if it is null in db, use:

```
Grade = row["Grade"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)row["Grade"]
```

Otherwise you want Grade as null if it is null in db, use:

```
Grade = row["Grade"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)row["Grade"]
```